# Odd notifications issue in the android app

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

I just received 2 notifications (comment replies) in quick succession.

I got a notification on my phone for the first one, and tapped to open it.

I then tapped on the notification in the notification listview within the app, and read the comment.

- I think I got another comment reply here, or possibly just before the step above.

I noticed that the red notification icon was still there, so i tapped it.

It brought up the same list, showing the first notification highlighted.

I couldn't get the first notification to stop being highlighted, the red notification icon to disappear, or see the second notification until I pulled down to refresh the notification list.

---

I think the issue is that it didn't auto refresh when clicking the red icon, possibly because it got confused with the first and second notification.